# Limit find request to one result

Tags: linux, bash

I've got the following command which should recursively go down folders and get the last modified date - which is perfect. However, sometimes it brings back more than one result for some reason. How can i just bring back the top one (the last modified file)

**The command is:**

```
find $1 -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' "{}" \; | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2-  | head
```

**The output is**

```
2015-08-17 21:52:00.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
2015-08-17 21:50:43.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
2015-08-17 21:44:36.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
2015-08-17 18:19:04.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
2015-08-17 18:15:37.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
2015-08-15 21:22:23.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
2015-08-15 18:37:51.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
2015-08-14 18:07:07.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
2015-08-14 17:55:53.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
2015-08-14 17:46:33.000000000 +0200 ./path/to/files/that/are/redacted.pdf
```

Comment: You just need to pipe the output to `head -n 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add 
 -n 1
to the end of your command